# NodeJS disconnecting when attempt MongoDB connection

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, mongoose

In my **app.js** file, I have the following code

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var port = 8080;
var util = require('util');
var router = require('./base/js/routes.js');
//==================================================================
app.use('/', router);

// start the server
app.listen(port, function(request, response) {
    console.log('Port 8080: Server Begins');
});
//==================================================================
var ipaddress = '123.456.789';
//==================================================================
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

var mongoURI = "mongodb://"+ ipaddress +":27017/test";
var MongoDB = mongoose.connect(mongoURI);
MongoDB.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log(err.message);
});
MongoDB.once('open', function() {
    console.log("mongodb connection open");
});
//==================================================================
```

The line **var MongoDB = mongoose.connect(mongoURI);** 
is causing nodeJS not to work. I do not know why. NodeJS is on port 8080 and MongoDB is on port 27017.

I am fairly certain I installed mongodb package (and opened the port correctly). I just do not understand why nodeJS doesnt work when i include that connection line.

Side Note: Also I have the package forever installed: **forever start -c nodemon app.js** for nodeJS. If that is any relevance.

Comment: Could you please share the exact error you get in the console?

Comment: it seems that your ip address is not correct. It should look like `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx` not `xxx.xxx.xxx`. And just make sure your id address is right, and your mongodb server has started.

Comment: That's an invalid IP address. Also, you must be seeing some error. Can you share that too?
Looks like your app must be crashing.

Comment: that ip address is just a dummy address. i use my actual one.

Answer (score 0):

You are using wrong IP address format.

First try to connect with your local mongoDB instance if it work then you to check the IP address your trying to connect is correct or not.

Add the correct error message if problem still remain same.

Answer (score 0):

change your mongod.conf file from /etc folder

In mongod.conf you need to change bindIp

If connection is local then set bindIp as

```
bindIp = 127.0.0.1
```

and if you want to use remote database then change bindIp as

```
bindIp = 0.0.0.0
```

then restart mongo service
hope this helps...